# Donors are receiving multiple receipts with ACH contributions

Tags: receipts, iats

Wordpress 4.7.3
Civi 4.6.26
iATS Payments for our processor

When donors make an ACH donation they get receipt right away and then a second one when the it clears their bank and the donation in Civi is changed from Pending to Completed. Is there a way to have Civi only send one receipt?

Comment: Very interested in this question. Happens to us as well. See http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/q/14233/105

Comment: I have been looking at when receipts have been sent and found a little more info that may help.  First time recurring ACH donations receive no receipt until the donation clears the donors bank. ACH donations that are not recurring, receive a receipt at the time of the donation and a second receipt when the donation clears the donors bank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dug into the code:

Firstly, in my humble view, it could use splitting into separate functions. One function is almost 400 lines long, making investigation hard.

I think I've seen the problem though. If your version of civicrm is less than 4.7.12, it won't activate a lot of the logic for recurring contributions.

https://github.com/iATSPayments/com.iatspayments.civicrm/blob/a92dd620a8975469e65372b3e34c812e5130faa1/iats.php#L244

`function _iats_civicrm_use_repeattransaction() {
  $version = CRM_Utils_System::version();
  return (version_compare($version, '4.7.12') < 0) ? FALSE : TRUE;
}`

For example, line 1425, which decides if to use line 1448, which currently reads:

`$complete['is_email_receipt'] = empty($options['is_email_receipt']) ? 0 : 1;
try {
  $contributionResult = civicrm_api3('contribution', 'completetransaction', $complete);
}`

**Update**
Oh, and there are also two unmerged patches from solid contributors: 
https://github.com/iATSPayments/com.iatspayments.civicrm/pulls

Comment: We upgraded to 4.7.17 (still not fully supported by iATS but I decided to try it)  and I made a non-recurring donation and did not receive a receipt for it.  I am assuming I will get the receipt once the transaction clears my bank which is how the system should work.

Comment: @CarlMiller neat! Drop me a line at john@civifirst.com to discuss fixing it up properly.